# java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

i have problem to reproduce a video with  `videoView.setVideoPath();`

in fact video doesn't reproduce..i don't know why. Video's path is correct.

This is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private VideoView videoView;
        private int position = 0;
        private MediaController mediaController;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            // Set the media controller buttons
            if (mediaController == null) {
                mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

                // Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController.
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


                // Set MediaController for VideoView
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            }


            try {
                // ID of video file.

                String videoUrl="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHdmkP-nfsA";
                videoView.setVideoPath(videoUrl);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            videoView.requestFocus();


            // When the video file ready for playback.
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {


                    videoView.seekTo(position);
                    if (position == 0) {
                        videoView.start();
                    }

                    // When video Screen change size.
                    mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                            // Re-Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController
                            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Who can help me?

Thanks in advance everybody!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

LOGCAT:

```
Couldn't open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHdmkP-nfsA: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHdmkP-nfsA
10-29 12:27:28.419 25932-25932/com.example.marco.ud D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
                                                                   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHdmkP-nfsA
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1137)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:988)
                                                                       at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:911)
                                                                       at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1102)
                                                                       at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1093)
                                                                       at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:356)
                                                                       at android.widget.VideoView.-wrap0(VideoView.java)
                                                                       at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:632)
                                                                       at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:656)
                                                                       at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:172)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1013)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2510)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1519)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7113)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: That is not a video. It is a Web page.

Answer (score 4):

You can not play a **YouTube** video directly to the **VideoView** or **ExoPlayer**, for that, first you have to download the video then set the locale path of that video to the method `VideoView.setVideoPath("path")`

If you want to play only **YouTube** videos then use [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), and if you only want to play other remote videos (.mp4, .ogg, .3gp etc.) then use the method `VideoView.setVideoURI("uri")`.

**Example-**

```
String videoUrl = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4";

try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String videoUrl
        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoview.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what another video url you are using instead of youtube video url?

Comment: suggest me a video url, please

Comment: @Bella check my updated answer and don't forget to upvote if it really helps you

Comment: If you want to play only YouTube videos then use YouTube Android Player API

Comment: i not want play video on youyube...i think that i must use exoplayer to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [**ExoPlayer**](https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html) instead of **VideoView**:

app gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.8'
```

layout xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

java code:

```java
PlayerView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
videoView.setPlayer(player);
// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"));
// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(fileEntity.getPath()));
// Prepare the player with the source.
player.prepare(videoSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

`VideoView.setVideoPath` requires a local path on the device. You should try `setVideoURI` instead if you want to play a remote MP4 or something else. [VideoView Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoPath(java.lang.String))

If you want to embed YouTube videos in your app, consider using the [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) or using something like a `WebView`

Comment: i tryed with   String videoUrl="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHdmkP-nfsA";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

            //videoView.setVideoPath(videoUrl);
            //videoView.start();
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri); BUT THE VIDEO IS NOT REPRODUCED

Comment: Try using an MP4 URI instead of the YouTube one and see if it works like that.

Comment: See my edit, if you just want to play YouTube videos.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue but it was because of corporate proxy server. I used same app over my mobile internet and it started working. Hope it save someone's time

Answer (score 0):

You are using `VideoView` which

> Displays a video file. The VideoView class can load images from
>   various sources (such as resources or content providers).

You might want to try `setVideoURI`

Or : [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) if min SDK > 16

Or use `SurfaceView` :

```
SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
           mediaPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
           mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
           mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: i tryed with String videoUrl="youtube.com/watch?v=JHdmkP-nfsA";; Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl); //videoView.setVideoPath(videoUrl); //videoView.start(); videoView.setVideoURI(uri); BUT THE VIDEO IS NOT REPRODUCED